# Vagrant VM doesn't get assigned IP

Tags: vagrant

I am trying to create a two VM from the centos/7 box with the following Vagrantfile (extract below):

```
config.vm.define "buildmaster" do |d|
    d.vm.hostname = "buildmaster"
    d.vm.network "private_network", ip: "10.217.65.200"
    d.vm.provision :shell, path: "scripts/install_ansible.sh"
    d.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
        v.name = "buildmaster"
    end
end

config.vm.define "vm#{1}" do |d|
    d.vm.hostname = "vm#{1}"
    d.vm.network "private_network", ip: "10.217.65.125"
    d.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
        v.name = "vm#{1}"
    end
end
```

The first VM gets the assigned IP which I can see with:

```
ip addr show

[vagrant@buildmaster ~]$ ip addr show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 ::1/128 scope host
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
link/ether 52:54:00:c3:c0:db brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 10.0.2.15/24 brd 10.0.2.255 scope global dynamic eth0
   valid_lft 78309sec preferred_lft 78309sec
inet6 fe80::5054:ff:fec3:c0db/64 scope link
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
link/ether 08:00:27:b5:1f:48 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 10.217.65.200/24 brd 10.217.65.255 scope global eth1
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:feb5:1f48/64 scope link
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

The second, however, doesn't get the assigned IP. I tried different IPs and ways of passing the IP, as a string, from a vector with string values, etc.

```
[vagrant@vm1 ~]$ ip addr show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 ::1/128 scope host
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
link/ether 52:54:00:c3:c0:db brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 10.0.2.15/24 brd 10.0.2.255 scope global dynamic eth0
   valid_lft 86367sec preferred_lft 86367sec
inet6 fe80::5054:ff:fec3:c0db/64 scope link
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
link/ether 08:00:27:33:93:fa brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe33:93fa/64 scope link
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Anybody else running into this problem and that has found a solution?

Comment: weird, did you try with other IPs ? is there anything in log

Comment: I did, same result. I suspect it is being track (and hopefully fixed): https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/7668#issuecomment-239283322

Answer (score 0):

For anyone running into the same problem. This is a problem with Vagrant and CentOS based boxes, yes Atomic Host as well.

I reported the issue here: https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/7711 and even though it says it is fixed, it is not in my recent experience with Vagrant 1.9.0. I still need to add this to the Vagrantfile when using CentOS or Atomic Host:

```
# Restart networking as a workaround for configured ip not showing up
$network_workaround = <<-NETWORK_WORKAROUND
    rm /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0
    systemctl restart network
NETWORK_WORKAROUND
config.vm.provision "network_workaround", type: "shell", privileged: true, inline: $network_workaround
```

Hope this helps.